# Home button parent fragment-child activity

Tags: android, fragment

I am having Activity A and Two Fragment called Fragment A and Fragment B.
In Fragment B List View is implemented. On Clicking of any list item the new activity get instantiated (Activity B). The Problem with the scenario 2
if the user pres the home button and again resume the activity then activity 2 is getting resumed.After resuming activity if the user press the back button then activity is getting into pause stage instead of returning back into to the parent fragment(Fragment 2)[image: Activity overflow].

Manifest for Activity 2

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.Activity2"
            android:label="@string/label1"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.Activity1"
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.test.activity.Activity1" />
  </activity>
```

Let me know what's causing this behavior. How can i retain fragment B when Activity B move into pause state.? or any other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could override the `onBackPressed` of your second activity, so that you always return to the first activity with fragment B shown.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
    intent.putExtra("some tag", "some text");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And in your first activity do something lke that:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) 
{
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    if(intent.getStringExtra("some tag").equals("some text"))
    {
        methodToDisplayFragmentB();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it for sure. But In My Activity1 i have `strict mode` config which will force close my Activity1 if it has more than one instance.

Comment: Then you should use the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` with your intent. Sorry for the late answer. Hope this helps.